# Displaying text in SVG using Java

Tags: java, svg, tags

I am successfully drawing a line in an svg using java. The line tag or name is shown using a GWT label in a div containing the svg. Is there a way to display tag using svg itself? (without using label and div's)

Comment: Presumably you create a text tag and put some text in it.

Answer (score 3):

```
OMSVGTextElement element;
private OMSVGSVGElement svgElement;
svgElement = doc.createSVGSVGElement();
element=doc.createSVGTextElement();
element.getElement().setInnerText("link label"); //the label
svgElement.appendChild(element);
```

This should do.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: svg text element allows us to provide a text for the drawing ( done using svg) without providing another div. So an extra div used to display text is avoided.